# how to deal with websocket disconnection issue, status code 1006 in /gofiber/websocket

Tags: websocket, go-fiber

I am trying to create chat application. Constantly facing websocket connection closing with status 1006 even though ping pong is established. How to deal with the disconnection? The package we are using is github.com/gofiber/websocket/v2

Answer (score 0):

checkout [ikisocket fiber wrapper](https://github.com/antoniodipinto/ikisocket) for one such example.

```golang
func (kws *Websocket) send(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case message := <-kws.queue:
            if !kws.hasConn() {
                if message.retries <= MaxSendRetry {
                    // retry without blocking the sending thread
                    go func() {
                        time.Sleep(RetrySendTimeout)
                        message.retries = message.retries + 1
                        kws.queue <- message
                    }()
                }
                continue
            }

            kws.mu.RLock()
            err := kws.ws.WriteMessage(message.mType, message.data)
            kws.mu.RUnlock()

            if err != nil {
                kws.disconnected(err)
            }
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        }
    }
}
```